# Can I assign values to a checkbox for checked and unchecked states?

Tags: php, checkbox

I have a single checkbox in a form which I want to assign values to for both checked and unchecked states.
The values are saved in a MySQL database. This is my php to retrieve the values.

```
<?php
// Value = 10.00
// This should be the checked value (initial state)
function getDel1()
{
global $con;
$get_del1 = "select * from delivery";
$run_del1 = mysqli_query($con, $get_del1);
while($row_del1=mysqli_fetch_array($run_del1)){
$leeds = $row_del1['delivery_leeds'];
echo "$leeds";
}
}
?>

<?php
// Value = 20.00
// This should be the unchecked value (user interaction)
function getDel2()
{
global $con;
$get_del2 = "select * from delivery";
$run_del2 = mysqli_query($con, $get_del2);
while($row_del2=mysqli_fetch_array($run_del2)){
$leeds = $row_del2['delivery_other'];
echo "$other";
}
}
?>
```

I can display the values independently by calling either function in a div which is adjacent to the form checkbox but I don't know how to assign those values to the form checkbox and then automatically update the div depending on the user interaction. Any suggestions?

Comment: use a ternary operator

Comment: I'm not sure I quiet follow, if the check box isn't "checked" it won't be sent? - If I got something wrong then do what Fred says

Comment: Fred, you mean an if statement? I can do that but it still leaves a gap as I don't know how to target the 2 states of the checkbox. Can you provide an html example?

Comment: plus, you tagged as javascript; relevance is? You also didn't post relevant code for your checkbox making this all that much more harder to provide you with a solution.

Comment: no need for an `if` statement, the ternary operator does it in one go.

Comment: I posted something for you below. @Steven

Comment: I tagged Javascript because I thought it may be relevant to the answer, sorry! The checkbox I have doesn't do anything yet and all I have done is put one of the functions in an adjacent div. This is it: <div class="bask-tot1"><p class="nobr"><span class="grey-lite">Delivery&nbsp;&nbsp;</span></p>
<p class="nobr"><input type="checkbox" name="deliver" value="" checked="checked" />&nbsp;Leeds</p></div>
<div class="bask-tot2"><p>£<?php getDel1(); ?></p></div>

Comment: If what I posted below doesn't answer the question, I will delete it and make room for other answers. @Steven please let me know either way.

Comment: Thanks for your help Fred, I'm trying to suss it out but forgive my ignorance, does the $_POST value rely on submission of the form? If not I can use it.

Comment: you're welcome Steven. Yes, the POST does rely on the form's submission and the checkbox needs to hold the name attribute for it. I.e.: `name="checkbox"` as an example. Again, without your full code and where your checkbox is, makes it harder to provide a solution and having us commenting back and forth. If your form uses a GET method, then change POST to GET, or REQUEST.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I'm getting a warning not to add too many comments so I'll be as explanatory as possible with this last one! The checkbox needs to display a value before the form is submitted as this value will be calculated into a total (added together with previous numerical values) So I'm looking for a way to update that value as soon as the checkbox is altered by a user.

Comment: reload my answer below. I've made a few edits.

Answer (score 0):

A ternary operator can take care of both assigned values and unassigned default values.

Example:

```
$checkbox = isset($_POST['checkbox']) ? $_POST['checkbox'] : "Default value if unchecked";
```

This is equivalent to doing: (which you can also use).

```
if (isset($_POST['checkbox'])){
    $checkbox=$_POST['checkbox'];

// do something, as in run a function

}
else{
    $checkbox="Default value if unchecked";

// do something else, as in run a different function

}
```

You can also remove the default text and do `""` in the ternary to leave it empty.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Footnotes:

Make sure the checkbox holds the name attribute.

I.e. `name="checkbox"` as an example.

and your form has a POST method. Use the appropriate method accordingly.

- So in your case and as seen in comments from code you left there, change `checkbox` in the arrays to `deliver`.

Your checkbox value can also use the following, as a ternary example:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="deliver" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['deliver']) ? $_POST['deliver'] : "Default value if unchecked"; ?>" />
```

Comment: Ok, I have messed around with this and have a partial fix thanks to your suggestions;   <?php
function getDel()
{
global $con;
$get_del = "select * from delivery";
$run_del = mysqli_query($con, $get_del);
while($row_del=mysqli_fetch_array($run_del)){
$leeds = $row_del['delivery_leeds'];
$other = $row_del['delivery_other'];
if (isset($_POST['deliver'])){
$deliver=$_POST['deliver'];
echo $other;
}else if (!isset($_POST['deliver'])){
echo $leeds;
}
}
}
?> BUT the checked and unchecked states are not being affected, it just updates after submit, not on the fly.

Comment: @Steven You're welcome Steven, glad to have been of help, *cheers*

Comment: Sorry, I pressed return prematurely!

Comment: @Steven the "on the fly" would be an JS/Ajax issue, and I won't be able to help you with that. I'm not very good with JS, TBH with you.

Comment: Is it possible to target the checkbox with php or do I need to use an onChange event in the form input area for this checkbox and use javascript?

Comment: @Steven the PHP method to target the input is in the way I modified your input in my answer using a ternary operator, or use an `if/else` method as outlined in my answer also. The onChange method (as far as I know) would be a way to do it, sure. and you're welcome.