# Echo checked if value 1

Tags: php, checkbox

This is my checkbox

```
<?php echo "<input type='checkbox' name='pcu' ".fieldvalue('1').==1 ? 'checked' : '' " value='1' />" ?>
```

If `fieldvalue` is `1` the box should be checked.

How to echo "checked=checked" if `fieldvalue` value is `1` and don't checked if `fieldvalue` is `0`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I assign values to a checkbox for checked and unchecked states?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33281558/can-i-assign-values-to-a-checkbox-for-checked-and-unchecked-states)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its must work for you

```
<?php 
If(fieldvalue==1)
{ 
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='pcu'  checked  value='1' />" ;
}else
{
echo "<input type='checkbox' name='pcu'  value='1' />" ;
}
?>
```

Or use short if :

```
 <input type='checkbox' name='pcu'    <?php 
    (fieldvalue==1 ? echo "checked " : "")  ?> value='1' />
```

Comment: is there another way to use html tags as property with dynamic solution